# (Hidden field author) This field is required

Tags: python, django, blogs

I followed this django tutorial on how to restrict other users in the blog post posts.
(The Video Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAH01Iy5AuE&list=PLCC34OHNcOtr025c1kHSPrnP18YPB-NFi&index=17)

But I get this message when I try to post

[image: The error]

(Hidden field author) This field is required?

This is my views.py file

```
from .forms import PostForm, EditForm
class AddPostView(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = "add_post.html"
    # fields = "__all__"
```

This is my forms.py file

```
from .models import Post, Category
from django import forms

# choices = [('uncategorized', "uncategorized"), ("gaming", "gaming"), ("youtube", "youtube"),]
choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name')
choice_list = []

for item in choices:
    choice_list.append(item)


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("title", "title_tag", "author", "category", "body")

        widgets = {
            "title": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Title"}),
            "title_tag": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Title Tag"}),
            "author": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "id": "Rashaad", "value": "", "type": "hidden"}),
            # "author": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "category": forms.Select(choices=choice_list, attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "body": forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Body"}),
        }


class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("title", "title_tag", "category", "body")

        widgets = {
            "title": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Title"}),
            "title_tag": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Title Tag"}),
            # "author": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "category": forms.Select(choices=choice_list, attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "body": forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Body"}),
        }
```

my add_post.html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<head>
    <title>Add Post...</title>
</head>

<h1>Add Blog Post...</h1>
<br/><br/>

<div class="form-group">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Post</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var name = "{{ user.id }}";
    document.getElementsByName("Rashaad").value;
</script>

{% else %}
<title>You are not allowed here</title>
<h1>You are not allowed here</h1>
<h2>(And you Know it)</h2>

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

If I forgot to mention a file please tell me

Comment: Remove `author` from **`PostForm.Meta.widgets`**

Comment: Sorry, It worked